# Match date on logfile and print line with awk

Tags: awk, sed, grep, tr

I have a log file that  may have the following lines among 100 other lines

```
hosta: Info: Tue Nov 25  19:44:39 2014>
User jwayman at position 170.198.3.141 disconnected 

hosta: Info: Tue Nov 23  19:44:39 2014>
User jho at position 170.198.3.141 disconnected 

hosta: Info: Tue Nov 26  19:44:39 2014>
User jho at position 170.198.3.141 disconnected
```

I need to look for occurrences of "disconnected" and then if the date ( from the line above it ) matches the today's date then I want to print  the following information:

```
user jho disconnected from server "hosta"
```

So I need to pull data from both lines and then do something with it.
I was thinking of doing this in a array and assign all occurrences to variables in array.
But I hope that someone can introduce an easier way of doing this, maybe with a `grep` and `awk`.

Comment: There's something wrong with your logging software if the 23rd, 25th and 26th are all Tuesdays!

Comment: just a typo on my side

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
awk -v today="$(date "+%a %b %d")" '$3 FS $4 FS $5 == today {f=1; next}
                                    f && /disconnected/ {print}
                                    f=0 ' file
```

#### Explanation

- `$(date "+%a %b %d")` returns on the format `Wed Nov 26`.
- `$3 FS $4 FS $5 == today {f=1; next}` checks is the current line has this format. If so, a flag `f` is activated.
- `f && /disconnected/ {print}` if the flag is set and the line contains `disconnected`, then prints it.
- `f=0` unsets the flag.

#### Test

Sample file:

```
$ cat a
hosta: Info: Tue Nov 25  19:44:39 2014>
User jwayman at position 170.198.3.141 disconnected 

hosta: Info: Tue Nov 23  19:44:39 2014>
User jho at position 170.198.3.141 disconnected 

hosta: Info: Wed Nov 26  19:44:39 2014>
User jho at position 170.198.3.141 disconnected 

hosta: Info: Wed Nov 26  19:44:39 2014>
User jho at position 170.198.3.141 here
```

Check the script:

```
$ awk -v today="$(date "+%a %b %d")" '$3 FS $4 FS $5 == today {f=1; next} f && /disconnected/ {print} f=0 ' a
User jho at position 170.198.3.141 disconnected
```

Comment: Hi This works great, but  how can I also print the hostname. Example hosta on the first line?

Comment: Mmm you could say `f=1; server=$1` and then `print server, $0`. Thar is, you catch the name and then print it back.

Comment: Hi thx again. I'm looking at the option and trying to understand the logic. Have not used this options and having some problem with how this works ..

Comment: @theuniverseisflat let me know what is unclear in the script I wrote! You can also take a look to a guide of awk: http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html

Answer (score 0):

Same concept as fedorqui (he beat me to the post by a few minutes) but with the exact output you asked for as opposed to just the input disconnected line.

```
awk -v date="$(date "+%a %b %d")" '$2 == "Info:" {
                                       if ($3" "$4" "$5==date) {
                                           s=$1; sub(/:$/,"",s)
                                       } else {
                                           s=""
                                       }
                                       next
                                   }
                                   s && ($NF == "disconnected") {
                                       print "user",$2,"disconnected from server \""s"\""
                                       s=""
                                       next
                                   }'
```

Explanation:

- `$2 == "Info:` are we looking at an `Info` line

  - `if ($3" "$4" "$5==date) {` is this line for today
  - `s=$1; sub(/:$/,"",s)` assign the server to `s` and strip off the trailing colon
  - `else` this is a line for some other day
  - `s=""` unset our server variable.
  - `next` skip to the next line
- `s && ($NF == "disconnected")` do we have a saved server and is this a disconnection line

  - `print "user",$2,"disconnected from server \""s"\""` print the desired output
  - `s=""` unset our server variable.
  - `next` skip to the next line

Comment: Thx I'm giving this a try

Comment: Hi. Thx this working and also prints the host name. Trying to figure out all the awk options and how this command work.

Comment: @theuniverseisflat The logic here is basically identical to the logic in fedorqui's answer (which he explained) the difference is that this captures the server (in `s`) and uses that in the output line.

Comment: thx I'm looking at both of ur replies   .. i know it's easy for u two .. but the combinations is throwing me off

Comment: @theuniverseisflat What are you having trouble understanding specifically?

Answer (score 0):

With GNU awk for gensub() and time functions:

```
$ awk -v RS= '
    BEGIN { today=strftime("%a%b%d") }
    (($3$4$5)==today) && /disconnected/ {
        print $8, $9, $NF, "from server \"" gensub(/:/,"\"","",$1)
    }
' file
User jho disconnected from server "hosta"
```